# (Seemingly) Interdependent HTML 'id' Attributes

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, button, decimal

## Overview

Hello, all. I'm trying to teach myself some HTML/CSS/JavaScript, and I've run into something which makes me think that I've misunderstood one or more aspects of the purpose and function of 'id' attributes in HTML.

Within the sections below, I've outlined what I'm trying to accomplish, the relevant sections of my code, and the (from my perspective) unexpected result that I'm getting.

Thanks in advance for sharing your thoughts and expertise; this site and its community has been immensely valuable to me in my coding journey thus far.

## What Am I Trying to Accomplish?

**Intended Function**
When I click the button, I want it to trigger my *numberChange()* function, which converts the *myNumber* variable to two decimal places and stores it in the *justTwoDecimals* variable.

**Intended Display**
I then want the value of *justTwoDecimals* to appear alone on the screen (i.e. I do not want the lengthier *myNumber* to appear).

## My Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var myNumber = 5.1234567;
    var justTwoDecimals = 0;


function numberChange()
{
    justTwoDecimals= parseFloat(myNumber).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("myNumber").innerHTML=myNumber;
    document.getElementById("justTwoDecimals").innerHTML=justTwoDecimals;
}

</script>

<button type="button" onClick="numberChange()">Click Here</button>


<p><u>Number With Just Two Decimals</u><br><a id="justTwoDecimals">Click the Button</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

## Unexpected Result

**Result Without Changes**
Using the above code, I click the button, but the 'Click the Button' text is nonresponsive, and doesn't convert to "5.12" as expected.

[FirstResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8u5o.jpg)

**Result With Changes**
When I add the code in Line 28, the *justTwoDecimals* value populates as expected, but unfortunately the *myNumber* value is now visible, clogging up the screen with numbers :)

[SecondResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NIM0.jpg)

```
26. <button type="button" onClick="numberChange()">Click Here</button>
27.
28. <p><u>Long Number Value</u><br><a id="myNumber">Click The Button</a></p>
29. <p><u>Number With Just Two Decimals</u><br><a id="justTwoDecimals">Click the Button</a></p>
```

## My Question

The answer is probably staring me right in the face, but why does the *myNumber* value need to appear on the screen in order for *justTwoDecimals* to populate correctly?

I thought that the entirety of the *numberChange()* function was always running, regardless of whether any values are appearing on the screen.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
document.getElementById("myNumber").innerHTML=myNumber;
```

On your original example, there is no element with `id="myNumber"` so, you are trying to get an element that does not exist, it throws an error, and stops executing the function, the next line never runs.

If you remove that line, then you get the expected result. The line above calculates the value you want to display, and the following line displays the value in the DOM.

```js
var myNumber = 5.1234567;
var justTwoDecimals = 0;

function numberChange() {
  justTwoDecimals = parseFloat(myNumber).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("justTwoDecimals").innerHTML = justTwoDecimals;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="numberChange()">Click Here</button>

<p>Number With Just Two Decimals</p>
<p id="justTwoDecimals">Click the Button</p>
```

The *result with changes* example runs because you are adding `myNumber` to the DOM, no exception is thrown, and the `justTwoDecimals` element gets updated.